# .xcworkspace not showing in git repository

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I have a project which has some of the pods installed.
I can see the .xcworkspace folder in my local workspace.
But it is not present in the remote git repository.
And I am not able to add it to git by `git add .xcworkspace/*`.
How can I add it to the local repository and then push it to remote?

Comment: Are you sure this directory isn't in your `.gitignore` ? What is the output of your `git add` ?

Comment: There is not output on git add.

Answer (score 3):

After cloning from git and after `pod install` the .xcworkspace will automatically come.You don't have to worry about. try...